# Script to return null on string values in Mule Datamapper

Tags: javascript, mule

I have an element of type double in my data mapper called capital. the values come from excel spreadsheet. but when there is no capital the values is "N/A" in excel. then i get the following error in the mapper:

> Caused by: com.opensys.cloveretl.component.spreadsheet.exception.SpreadsheetException: Cannot get number value from cell of type String in M3 in record 1, field 13 ("Capital"), metadata

How can i script the mapper to return null or 0 whenever a value of type string comes through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any Java methods available on the data types when you are working with the script.  It looks like the problem here is that you don't know if the input value is going to be a String ("N/A") or a decimal value.  To solve that, you can take the approach of converting it to a string to test it and then take the appropriate action.  I don't have an excel data mapper set up at the moment so I didn't try this out, but I think something like this should work.

```
output.Captial = ((""+input.Capital).equals("N/A") ? 0 : input.cellValue);
```

By adding the ("" + input.Capital), you are casting it to a String, just like it would in Java.